Smaller wing toggles or larger holes?
Hi — I accidentally pulled a one-sided doorknob out of a closet door. I’m reattaching with wing toggles. 1/8” toggles are a little too big. Is it advisable to get smaller toggles or to drill bigger holes? Thank you.

Pictures are always a good idea so we can see what you see.

Picture of the door knob might help with different solutions.  If it screws in, then toothpicks and wood glue in the hole will help.

If possible, I would suggest bolting through, with a washer on the back side to distribute the force, rather than trying to put an anchor into a thin door skin.

Hollow or solid door?
